# Access bundled Java file from outside the JVM

Tags: java

Is it possible to access a bundled Java file from outside the JVM?  My particular issue is that I have Ruby scripts bundled with my application that I need to execute from the command line.

The Ruby scripts are located at src/main/resources, and to execute them I am using a third party exe in Windows where the final command looks something like:
custom_ruby.exe -script PATH_TO_SCRIPT

So, I need to get a file system path to a bundled Java resource.  Is this even possible?  If not I am planning to read the Ruby Script in Java, and simply write it to a temp directory.  If there is a more elegant solution I'd like to know.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a bundled Java file? If you mean a file in a jar/zip then you can certainly read the file from the jar/zip. I don't think there's an instrinsic way of pointing the filesystem to the file in the jar/zip though. Unless there are some *nix magic scripts.

Comment: If it were just a Jar then I suppose I could expand it out and find the file.  However, I'm building an RCP (Eclipse Platform) application, so the final result is just an executable.

Comment: The question seems really dumb, so I must be reading it wrong. ;-)  A file system path obviously only has granularity down to a file.  If I understand right, you want to reach into an EXE for a jar inside an OSGI bundle with the script you need.

Comment: Indeed my initial thought was that it was impossible, but there are some smart people out here so I didn't want to overlook an obvious solution.  I'm just going to copy the files at runtime to a temp directory.

Comment: pls in the future include detailed info about your question. Deleting my answer as does not apply under the conditions explained in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Class.getResource()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). Checkout an example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/ClassgetResourceStringnamerelativetotheclasslocation.htm).

Comment: I guess the OP refers to accessing the jar file from outside the VM.

Comment: whatever the resource be as long as he has to pass the resource externally he has to get hold of the resource url or stream

Comment: Those are the methods used to get the resource within the java application.  As I said, I could do that, then just write the files to a temp directory somewhere else.  Was hoping to avoid that.